# Add watermark to document BODY using OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I have a MS Word document (.docx) and I'd like to add a watermark to the document using OpenXML. I've searched around and the only example that I was able to find is when the watermark is added to the header of the document, like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/010e55ae-dc56-4e55-af23-02ad268d6bb9/generating-a-custom-watermark-with-open-xml-sdk?forum=oxmlsdk).

This won't work for me, because the document already has text in the header, and it must be preserved. The example actually replaces the Header section with a new one that contains the watermark image.

Another challenge is to add the watermark in the body of the document, and behind or in front of the document, so that the content of the body remains readable. I've read an example in which the watermark is added after the content and there were issues if the content contained images.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too broad and not really clear... Do you want the watermark on all pages, or just one page? If all pages, then it has to go into the Header. Create a document with a watermark using Word's built-in functionality, save the document and open it in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool in order to see the underlying Word Open XML.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you can't add your watermark to the existing header content.

But as you say, it can interact in strange ways with document content (particularly tables).

A hack you can try, to put the watermark in the document body: put all your body content in a 2 row x 1 column table.  The "watermark" image is anchored in the first cell, and the table header row set to repeat each page.  The rest of your document content goes in the second cell.  This approach also has some issues, which may or may not affect you...